# How to capture the outbound net traffic after url rewrite points to an external url

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Is there a way to capture the outbound network traffic after IIS url rewrite happens?

I have a local IIS website that is configured to rewrite certain local url to an external site. The rule is set to be rewrite.I need to capture the IIS outbound traffic to the rewritten external url, to debug some issues with Fiddler, but didn't find where is the proper place to set the Fiddler proxy.

I have tried set the proxy in ARRC, but seems the proxy chain happens before actual rewrite instead after it.

Also tried to set the proxy in machine.config, not working again.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" bypassonlocal="false" autoDetect="false"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use Fail request tracing to achieve your requirement.

FRT can be used with the URL rewrite module to trace how rewrite rules were applied to the request URL.

More detail about how to install it and use it ,you could refer to below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

After used it, you could see the details of outbound role request in log files which path is C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles.

Part of the log file:

[image]

Comment: That's for inbound rewrites, not outbound.